# Print user uploaded logo in twig template

Tags: 8, theming

How can I print a user uploaded logo (via the theme appearance UI) in a twig template?

For example, in `block--system-branding-block.html.twig` we can use

```
Available variables:
- site_logo: Logo for site as defined in Appearance or theme settings.

  <img src="{{ site_logo }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" />
```

What do I need to do to make that variable (or a custom variable) available to another twig template, like `menu.html.twig`?

I have found many solutions, but all them involved hardcoding the logo file name or location, both of which are obviously not user friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of you need to do is to [**Add New Regions to your Theme**](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-regions-to-a-theme) like `logo_region` and then print the site logo on desired twig template with below code:

```
{% if logo_region %}
  <div class="my-style">
    {{ page.logo_region }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

And finally enable/place your site brand in created region (logo_region) on **Block layout** page:`admin/structure/block`

Comment: Sounds good thank you! I was hoping for more simple way, but as this is the most user friendly and fool proof method, I happily accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @petergus : your welcome ;)